# Iterating over numbers to add them returns array in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having some behavior I can't figure out.  I have a method that loops over an object array and sums several values from the objects and I'm displaying that in a template.  It loads with expected sums but if I change any value in the inputs it produces what looks like a comma separated array of the individual values.

The method that sums the values is this:

```
  herdTotal(): {kind: number, labor: number, acres: number} {
    const total = {kind: 0, labor: 0, acres: 0};
    for (const herd of this.manor.livestock) {
      total.kind += this.herdKind(herd);
      total.labor += this.herdLabor(herd);
      total.acres += herd.acres;
    }
    return total;
  }
```

The result is displayed in the template through these fields: (near the bottom "totalHerd()."

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-sm">
  <thead class="thead-light">
  <tr class="row">
    <th class="small font-weight-bold col">Herd</th>
    <th class="small font-weight-bold col-md-1 text-center">RI</th>
    <th class="small font-weight-bold col-md-1 text-center">Yield</th>
    <th class="small font-weight-bold col-md-2 text-center">Acres</th>
    <th class="small font-weight-bold col-md-2 text-center">Labor</th>
    <th class="small font-weight-bold col-md-2 text-right">Kind</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let herd of manor.livestock" class="row">
    <td class="col">{{herd.herdType}}: {{herdHeadCount(herd)}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-1 text-center">{{herderIndex(herd)}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-1 text-center">{{herdYield(herd)}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2">
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="herd.acres">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-2 text-center">{{herdLabor(herd)}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2 text-right">{{herdKind(herd) | number}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="col text-right font-weight-bold" colspan="3">Totals:</td>
    <td class="col-md-2 text-right">{{herdTotal().acres | number}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2 text-right">{{herdTotal().labor | number}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2 text-right">{{herdTotal().kind | number}}d</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As I said, they load properly at first, but if I change any of the acres field values I get a list.  I would imagine it thinks theres a string there but everything is typed as a number and even if I try to parseInt to scrub it I get an error saying I'm trying to pass a number value.

Anyone have an idea what is going on?  Thanks for any insight.

Comment: In your number pipe - are you parsing the input value for acrres into a number? - this line "<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="herd.acres">" will yield a string value upon input

Comment: No.  I'm not sure I have encountered that before.  I'll try to look that up thanks.

Comment: All inputs (even those with type "number" designated) will return a string. In the case of numeric inputs the return will be a string representation of the number (which is why you need to parse it to a number before calucations are preormed - such as adding / multiplying etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments  - all inputs will yield a string - this will need to be converted to a number for the summing - try changing the function as follows:

```
 herdTotal(): {kind: number, labor: number, acres: number} {
    const total = {kind: 0, labor: 0, acres: 0};
    for (const herd of this.manor.livestock) {
      total.kind += this.herdKind(herd);
      total.labor += this.herdLabor(herd);
      total.acres += parseInt(herd.acres); // note the parseInt here
    }
    return total;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I get an error when I build about argument type number not assignable to type string.  herd.acres is a number.  I guess that doesn't matter but it chaffs me to leave an error message like that.

Comment: Yeah that would be because you are typing it at the top of the function - you could type it to "any" or - put in a function on the keyup or change of content on the text input to convert it into a number before passing the value into the ngModel.-ie: the value that is stored into the data is a number (rather than converting it at the summing function).

Comment: I've been doing some googling and can't find an answer.  As you say, the best approach would seem to sanitize it on input but I can't find an example of how.  the (change) bind would work but I'm looking to maintain the functionality that the numbers update as soon as the entry is change, not when it loses focus.